# Sharepoint Multi Authentication

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I need to find out how I can allow our Sharepoint portal to support both windows authentication and form based authentication. The objective is to allow those users in our Active directory to sign into the portal using their active directory credentials, and at the same time we want to allow those users who don't belong to our active directory to register an account online and be able to access our sharepoint portal after their account is approved by an admin.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to enable the Dual Authentication for the SharePoint Site. [Here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/articles/HowToConfigPublishingSiteWithDualAuthProvidersAndAnonAccess.aspx) one of the class article in the subject
Also you need to deploy the controls for enabling the user to register and create login refer [this](http://www.codeplex.com/fba)